# How do I style a button as a toggle that changes styling when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm using the following code to change prices in my pricing table:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("prijs-small");
  if (x.innerHTML === "17,50") {
    x.innerHTML = "13,50";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "17,50";
  }

  var x = document.getElementById("prijs-medium");
  if (x.innerHTML === "58") {
    x.innerHTML = "30,50";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "58";
  }

  var x = document.getElementById("prijs-large");
  if (x.innerHTML === "128,50") {
    x.innerHTML = "61";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "128,50";
  }
}
```

```css
.prijs-button {
  background-color: white;
  color: #012d5d;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<button class="prijs-button" onclick="myFunction()">150/350</button>

<div id="prijs-small">17,50</div>
<div id="prijs-medium">58</div>
<div id="prijs-large">128,50</div>
```

Now I want to style a toggle that does the same, with on the one side showing 150 (people icon) and other side 350 (people icon) as shown in this example:

[image]

As I'm using a button now to make the prices change, how can I turn this into this toggle? The green half should be the active part.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Consider using a two-state element as the basis, like a checkbox (can be checked or not checked, whereas a button doesn't have this distinction).  There are a lot of tutorials on the mechanics of how to create the styling, you can google javascript toggle switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this do? I've used a checkbox and styled it to look like a pill.  Hopefully it's self-explanatory but if not drop me a comment and I'll elaborate.

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}

#mybutton {
  width: 8rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border-radius: 100rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#mybutton input {
  display: none;
}

#mybutton>label {
  display: flex;
}

.side {
  width: 50%;
  padding-inline: 0.15rem;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3rem;
  background-color: white;
  transition: background-color, color 300ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#mybutton input:not(:checked)~.left {
  background-color: #35CB8C;
  color: white;
  transition: background-color, color 300ms;
}

#mybutton input:checked~.right {
  background-color: #35CB8C;
  color: white;
  transition: background-color, color 300ms;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div id='mybutton'>
  <label for='mybutton-checkbox'>
  <input type=checkbox id='mybutton-checkbox'>
  <div class='side left'>25<i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <div class='side right'>100<i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put two buttons next to each other with some border radiuses applied to them.

Some POC version here:

```css
div.toggle {
  font-size: 0; /* this is to remove empty inline space between two buttons. if you don't like it, you can use flexbox */
}

button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

button.left {
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
}

button.right {
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle">
  <button class="left">25</button>
  <button class="right">100</button>
</div>
```

Adding an image or icon inside button is totally possible so you can do if if you want.

Answer (score 0):

By inserting two buttons with different images you might get the result you are seeking.
Then by using in CSS `border-bottom-left: (The amount of px you want)px and border-top-left: (The amount of px you want)px` you can style you buttons.